# How to write $\Bbb Z_q\rtimes\Bbb Z_p$ as $\langle a,b\mid a^p=b^q=1,aba^{-1}=b^{i_0}\rangle?$

Tags: finite-groups, group-presentation, semidirect-product, combinatorial-group-theory

I am referring specifically to this example http://planetmath.org/groupsoforderpq

In Case 2, the group should be $\mathbb{Z}_q\rtimes\mathbb{Z}_p$.

> How do we write it in the presentation of $$G=\langle a,b\mid a^{p}=b^{q}=1,aba^{-1}=b^{i_{0}}\rangle?$$

Thanks for help.

I am thinking of something in the directions of internal semidirect product, but not sure exactly how.

Comment: You just need to choose $i_0$ with $1< i_0 < q$ and $i_0^p \equiv 1 \bmod q$. For example, if $p=5$ and $q=11$ you could choose $i_0=3$. But you could also choose $i_0=4,5$ or $9$. All of these choices give rise to isomorphic groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks. In your opinion, is the level of rigor enough for that proof in the link? I like it, but I have seen proofs of classifying groups of order $pq$ that are significantly longer and more complicated, eg in Hungerford.